# can i make a this linq statement iteration from a collection in a single statement?

Tags: c#, linq

```
bool isExist = objCustomization.CustomSettings.Where(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID).Any();

if (isExist)
{
    chkFixLimit.Checked = objCustomization.CustomSettings.Where(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID).FirstOrDefault().IsDefaultLimit;
}
else chkFixLimit.Checked = false;
```

Comment: @sayse: You shouldn't modify the fundamental nature of the question. The code the OP provided is the code he wanted converting. If you think it should have a common query variable that is part of an answer, not a modification to the question.

Comment: @Sayse - I support the rollback, don't apply cosmetics that may interfere with the actual question.

Comment: @Chris - I made care to not modify the question, but it makes the question easier to read when not having to compare queries to see if they're the same

Comment: @sayse: The question is "I have this code that I would like to put in one statement". Changing the code changes the question in at least a small way. If the OP hadn't realised he could do your refactor then changing the question doesn't help him as much as noting it clearly in a comment or answer. And I presume he didn't realise because he didn't do it.

Comment: @Chris - Fair enough, Looking at some of the answers I see your point

Comment: Note that `FirstOrDefault` also takes a predicate as argument. So what you have for `Where` can be directly sent to `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default value for boolean is `false` so you even don't need any conditions - just select first or default `IsDefaultLimit` value:

```
chkFixLimit.Checked =
   objCustomization.CustomSettings
       .Where(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID)
       .Select(p => p.IsDefaultLimit)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

UPDATE (answer for your comment) in case you have non-boolean value or default value (zero for integer) do not fit your requirements, with [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty.aspx) you can provide own default value if there is no items matching your condition:

```
maxCountCmb.SelectedIndex = 
    objCustomization.CustomSettings
        .Where(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID)
        .Select(p => p.DefaultFreeCount)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
        .First();
```

Comment: if it were not a bool type

Comment: i mean it were like this maxCountCmb.SelectedIndex = objCustomization.CustomSettings.Where(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID).FirstOrDefault().DefaultFreeCount;

Comment: Note that `FirstOrDefault` can also take a predicate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can:

```
var item = objCustomization.CustomSettings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID);

chkFixLimit.Checked = item != null && item.IsDefaultLimit;
```

Or single statement, as you wish:

```
chkFixLimit.Checked = new Func<bool>(() => {
    var item = objCustomization.CustomSettings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID);
    return item != null && item.IsDefaultLimit;
}).Invoke();
```

Comment: That is not a single statement.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to applaud your single statement solution or cry a little. ;-)

Comment: @Chris it's more a sarcasm, no a code I would ever use in real-life situation.

Comment: Its ok. I did guess that. :)

Answer (score 2):

This not in one line but it is more readable, you can change:

```
var setting = objCustomization.CustomSettings              
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType 
                                  && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID);

chkFixLimit.Checked = setting == null ? false : setting.IsDefaultLimit;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chkFixLimit.Checked = objCustomization.CustomSettings
  .Where(p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType 
     && p.CategoryID == selCategoryID)
  .Select(c => c.IsDefaultLimit)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Actually, since `default(bool)==false`, you don't even need the `?? false` part.

Comment: @the_joric I have strange feeling that I had seen something similar... deja vu!

Answer (score 1):

That code is more-or-less the use case of the [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method. If something exists, return the first such item, and return a default value (`null` for reference types) if it doesn't. So you could just do:

```
var item = objCustomization.CustomSettings.FirstOrDefault
               (p => p.CustomizationType == selCustomizationType && p.CategoryID)
```

and as result, the `item` object will either be `null` (assuming you indeed work with a reference type), or it will have a value.
After that you can just check that, with a simple

```
chkFixLimit.Checked = (item == null) ? false : item.IsDefaultLimit;
```